# Kafka Consumer being Starved because of unbalance

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka and think I am missing something on how partition queues get balanced on a topic

We have 5 partitions and 2 consumers on a topic.  The topic has a null key so I assume Kafka randomly picks a new partition to add the new record to in a round robin fashion.

This would mean one consumer would be reading from 3 partitions and the other 2.  If my assumption is right (that the records get evenly distrusted across partitions) the consumer with 3 partitions would be doing more work (1.5x more).  This could lead to one consumer doing nothing while the other keeps working hard.

I think you should have an even divisible number of partitions to consumers.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The unit of parallelism in consuming Kafka messages is the partition. The routine scenario for consuming Kafka messages is getting messages using a data stream processing engine like Apache Flink, Spark, and Storm that all of them distributed processing on CPU cores. The rule is the maximum level of parallelism for each consumer group can be the number of partitions. Each consumer instance of a consumer group (say CPU cores) can consume one or more partitions and on the other hand, each partition can be consumed by **just one consumer instance** of each consumer group.

- If you have more CPU core than the number of partitions, some of them
  will be idle.
- If you have less CPU core than the number of    partitions, some of
  them will consume more than one partitions.
- And    the optimized case    is when the number of CPU cores and
  Kafka partitions are equal.

The image can describe all well:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> If my assumption is right (that the records get evenly distributed across partitions) the consumer with 3 partitions would be doing more work (1.5x more). This could lead to one consumer doing nothing while the other keeps working hard.

Why would one consumer do nothing? It would still process records from those 2 partitions [assuming of course, that both the consumers are in same group]

> I think you should have an even divisible number of partitions to consumers.

Yes, that's right. For maximum parallelism, you can have as many number of consumers, as the #partitions, e.g. in your case 5 consumers would give you max parallelism.

Comment: What I am thinking is one consumer would EVENTUALLY do nothing.  Lets just say each of the 5 partition has 10 records (and no more records are being published) and it takes a second per record.  Consumer A has 30 records it will process and Consumer B has 20 records.  After 20 seconds Consumer B has 0 records and Consumer A still has 10 records and will be processing for 10 more seconds while Consumer B does nothing.

Comment: I don't think that's an exactly correct analogy. As far as I know, fetch time from partition doesn't grow linearly with the number of partitions.

Comment: http://aseigneurin.github.io/2017/08/04/why-kafka-streams-didnt-work-for-us-part-2.html
If you look at the section handling large volume of data and the example of where most records end up on one partition.  This is what I am talking about.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: But they clearly say, their distribution of keys is skewed, which is causing this. Given the context of this question, I assumed we're using the default partitioning scheme. If your partitioning scheme itself is skewed, then the problem is not caused by the mismatch in the numbers of partitions/consumers. It's somewhere else. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Isnt the goal of a partitioning scheme to evenly distributed messages?  If so, what I am saying if 5 partitions is a bad choice.  Should be 4,6,8 etc.  Something divisible by the number of consumers.

Comment: The basic premise of your assumption is correct, but there's more to that. Only assuring number of partitions are divisible by no. of consumers doesn't solve all problems. If your partitioning scheme is messed up, it would still be problematic. That's what I was trying to point out. Let's take a simple example. Let's say we push all messages with the same key, which will route the messages to same partition always. No relation between #partitions and #consumers will make things better.

Comment: I agree.  My original question was the assumption the topic had null key.   Do you know how the messages get disturbed to different partitions when the key is null?  I assumed evenly (like a dealer dealing a deck of card).  In this case I think it makes sense to have the consumers divisible by the number of partitions.

Comment: Yes, you're right. In that case it's a round robin strategy.

Comment: My bad, it's called range assignment strategy, there's a difference between those two.

Answer (score 0):

There is an assumption built into your understanding that each partition has exactly the same throughput. For most applications, though, that may or may not be true. If you set up your keying/partitioning right, then the partitions should hopefully be close to equal, especially with a large and diverse keyspace if you average them out over a large period of time. But in a more practical, realistic sense, you'll probably have some skew at any given time anyway, and your stream processing setup will need to tolerate that. So having one more partition assigned to a particular consumer is probably not going to make a big difference.

Answer (score -1):

Your understanding is correct. May be there is data skew. You can check how many records are there in each partition by using offset checker or other tool.